# Using openCV, how do I change the resolution and not the size of the image?

Tags: ios, opencv

This may be a basic question, but I'm new to openCV and I find the documentation to be very poor. I think I would like to use the resize function to get a new image at the same size as the original, but at a lower resolution.

All documentation I find acts as if resolution and size are the same thing and I have absolutely no idea what these parameters mean. Different sources seem tho show a different version of resize than what I see in the headers:

```
CV_EXPORTS_W void resize( InputArray src, OutputArray dst,
                      Size dsize, double fx=0, double fy=0,
                      int interpolation=INTER_LINEAR );
```

If I keep dsize the same size as my original, what do x and y represent and how would I get a resolution of say 72 dpi?

Comment: resolution and size are the same thing for the image/datastructure itself. Just for printing/displaying the size might be different. If you want to access a pixel (that's what is done in image processing), how would you access a pixel location if you work with image size in inch and dpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's me explain something straight: when you load your image to a memory, you have, in a good approximation, matrix of numbers with given amount of rows and cols. And from the definition of dpi, which is amount of individual dots that can be placed in line of one inch, you have a lack of "inch" in the memory. How would you define dpi in case of matrix stored in memory? It makes no sense to talk about it only according to the memory. So that is way in opencv (and perhaps in any other processing library) you have resolution and size concepts equal.

Maybe  you would like to achieve something as "artificial" dpi lowering? Something that "looks like" image being printed with lower dpi? In that case, why don't you try resizing down and up the same image iteratively to achieve this result.

And `cv::resize()` function does change the size either by given destination size (param `dsize`) or scale factors (`fx` and `fy`).